# How to implement push notifications in React Native when the app is closed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, push-notification

I'm studying React Native right now, and I'm trying to figure out how to enable the reception of Push Notifications even when the app is closed, just as Facebook does.

I'm a web developer, so I'm not used to mobile apps' "Manifest" logic. Where should I start from? 
Thank you!

Comment: it is documented on react-native page. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/pushnotificationios.html and here https://medium.com/differential/how-to-setup-push-notifications-in-react-native-ios-android-30ea0131355e

Comment: I had already found that page, the point is that I'd like the notification to be received even if the app is closed (NOT in background), so an app with a service always awake on the phone to listen to that notifications :)

Comment: then you might not understand your question yourself. if an app exited/terminated. notifications will not be available. it needs to run in background for such services to be available.

Comment: Most social apps have the ability to "stay awake" even if closed, that's a feature you control in the settings of the phone (there is one option like "Apps allowed to stay awake in the background"). This is what I mean for background, I'm not referring to the action of navigating to another app or home screen!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It seems that since you are a web developer, mobile app is not yet familiar with you. Actually, setting up push notification will require a few more official steps (differently on iOS and Android), and after everything is set, the push notification will happen between Apple server (or Google server) and smartphone's OS (which is iOS or Android), so the push notifications will come to the phone no matter what (without knowing/caring your app is opened or closed ^^)

In the programming code of our app, we can do our logics when the notifications come based on 2 cases: **users is using the app** or **app is not running** (not running means users are not using your app, and it is either staying awake in the background or users have exited it completely - e.g. pressing Home button twice on iPhone, and swiping the app away)

Actually, If you want your app to stay awake in the background, you can add some settings to the "manifest"-like files (of course differently on iOS & Android). However, my experiences taught me that keeping the app awake will encourage the users to complain and delete our app (my previous app's user once complained about *his iPhone's battery was consumed greatly* because of my app ^^)

If you really want to keep your app awake, you can set it in the settings, then in the push notifications' data, you can include extra parameters, and finally in the function of receiving push-notifications in your app, you can do anything with those parameters!

In short, you may just need to config push-notification properly for your app, and Apple/Google will do the rest, either your app is running in background or totally closed, it will receive the notifications. Hope you can find a good solution based on my explanation. If there's still something unclear, feel free to post here some more details on your needs, thanks!

This is the library I'm using with my previous react-native project: (they also have tutorial there ^^)

https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification

**ADDED EXPLANATION:** (based on author's needs):

- *The goal is: the user will register/login in the app, and will subscribe to some future events.*

=> whenever users open the app, data will be sent to Apple/Google server to get a token, and you will use this token together with user's subscribe data to send all to **your own push-server** (you can use PHP or node.js server or whatever)

- *When an event gets updated a notif. should be sent to all the users who are going to that event. So a notif. aimed to certain users only.*

=> like the above answer, data will be sent every time users open app (or change settings, you can do it in your logic of the app, because data will be kept **your own push-server**, which means on that server, you can even see user list, and can aim to certain users - it depends on what data will be sent to the users from the smartphone, but users may refuse inputting too much information like name, age or email, but it's up to your service's need ^^)

- *By clicking on it, the app will open and a certain page of the app (pre-existing) will be shown.*

=> by default, when an notif. is clicked, the app will be opened for sure, and here once again, you can add extra parameters to the notifications (which is the landing page you need, then in the function of you app, just go there - but it may get extra logics for this. Besides, when to push notification, and which data should be pushed etc. will be controlled by *your own server*)

- *It seems like the most complicated part will be the "sending to certain users" one!*

=> I explained this already, but you're right, actually it's complicated, because you need to create **your own server** with lots of API and logics based on your needs, and it need a few more steps (complicated one because you need to register many things with Apple & Google, then adding their Certificates into your own server etc.)

Hopefully you will achieve it, I suggest you play around and truly understand how push-notifications work first (for both sides - your own server and your application) - Good luck, though ^^

Comment: Hi and thanks for your reply! :) Actually, I noticed that "react-native-push-notification" should work even if the app is closed, could you confirm it? The goal is: the user will register/login in the app, and will subscribe to some future events. When an event gets updated a notif. should be sent to all the users who are going to that event. So a notif. aimed to certain users only. By clicking on it, the app will open and a certain page of the app (pre-existing) will be shown. It seems like the most complicated part will be the "sending to certain users" one!

Comment: I don't actually need the app to stay awake, I only need the notifications to be received even when the app is closed :)

Comment: Coincidence ^^ ! I've also added the "react-native-push-notification" in my answer. *should work even if the app is closed* => this is confirmed & correct, and please also see my newer edit, which will answer your other questions!

Comment: Thank you so much! How should I handle the fact that I want certain notifications to be sent to some users only? Coming from the web-world, I see this logic as an "Observable", in which the client listens for changes on the backend, but it seems that Push Notif. are the exact opposite!

Comment: Please see my edited answer above, which will answer everything. Since you are a web-developer, building your own server for storing push notification's data is easy ^^ There's still a lot more to go through until you achieve your need, but just follow my direction, which will be fine (because I was also web-developer before jumping into mobile-app world ^^ )

Comment: That's perfect, thank you :) The app will be a kind of "companion" app for a web-app which will be made, so there will be an existing backend (NodeJS or others, I'm just the Front-End developer!). I'm wondering if it could be integrated to Google Firebase Notifications, I see they've got a good dashboard to handle notifications, but the logic behind them will be stored in our backend, hmmm...

Comment: It can be integrated to Google Firebase for sure, because the logics from 2 sides (backend and application) are totally separated and different. I think you and your back-end developers will find a good solution together ^^